# How can i set custom directive in database.yml as default directive

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to set report directive as default directive in my rails application

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: osvdb
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: jeet
report:
  adapter: mysql
  database: report_db
  host: localhost
  username: root 
  password: jeet
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I think this will solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
report: &defaults
  adapter: mysql
  database: osvdb
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: jeet

development:
  <<: *defaults
```